# How can i have exit status of zero with kill command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using this command to kill

```
ps aux | bla bla | xargs kill -9
```

It's working fine but the problem is it also sometimes tries to kill subprocess id which already got killed because of parent process kill so it returns as non zero exit status.

Is there any way to make as exit status 0?

Comment: Why do you care what the exit status of `kill` is?

Comment: Depends entirely on `bla bla`. Looks like you should keep track of which processes you started in the first place; then the rest is very very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial way is to just ignore any non-zero exit status:

```
ps aux | bla bal | xargs kill || true
```

(You probably shouldn't be using `kill -9`; it's a debugging tool, not intended for production use.)

Comment: [Why you should not use `kill -9`](http://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill/) Or in serious wording, [this link](http://novosial.org/shell/kill-9/index.html)

Comment: I would also suggest using [`-r`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/xargs/) option for `xargs`, if it is `GNU xargs`...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution des did not work for me everywhere.

The following simple, one-line solution works fine with all kinds of Linux/Unix. I tested it with Ubuntu, Mint, Centos, Amazon Linux, and Alpine (Docker).

This runs in a new shell and this way you can control properly the exit code.

```
/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/killall -q <process-name>; exit 0'
```